# Split column of comma-separated numbers into multiple columns based on value

Tags: r, split, dplyr, tidyr, strsplit

I have a column `f` in my dataframe that I would like to spread into multiple columns based on the values in that column. For example:

```r
df <- structure(list(f = c(NA, "18,17,10", "12,8", "17,11,6", "18", 
                           "12", "12", NA, "17,11", "12")), .Names = "f", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                        10L), class = "data.frame")

df
#            f
#  1      <NA>
#  2  18,17,10
#  3      12,8
#  4   17,11,6
#  5        18
#  6        12
#  7        12
#  8      <NA>
#  9     17,11
#  10       12
```

How would I split column `f` into multiple columns indicating the numbers in the row. I'm interested in something like this:

```r
          6    8    10   11   12   17   18    
1         0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2         0    0    1    0    0    1    1
3         0    1    0    0    1    0    0
4         1    0    0    1    0    1    0
5         0    0    0    0    0    0    1
6         0    0    0    0    1    0    0
7         0    0    0    0    1    0    0
8         0    0    0    0    0    0    0
9         0    0    0    1    0    1    0
10        0    0    0    0    1    0    0
```

I'm thinking I could use`unique` on the `f` column to create the seperate columns based on the different numbers and then do a `grepl` to determine if the specific number is in column `f` but I was wondering if there was a better way.  Something similar to `spread` or `separate` in the `tidyr` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `tidyr::separate_rows` will be as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(f, sep=",") %>%
  mutate(f = ifelse(is.na(f),0, f)) %>%
  count(ind, f) %>%
  spread(f, n, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-2) %>% as.data.frame()

   # ind 10 11 12 17 18 6 8
# 1    1  0  0  0  0  0 0 0
# 2    2  1  0  0  1  1 0 0
# 3    3  0  0  1  0  0 0 1
# 4    4  0  1  0  1  0 1 0
# 5    5  0  0  0  0  1 0 0
# 6    6  0  0  1  0  0 0 0
# 7    7  0  0  1  0  0 0 0
# 8    8  0  0  0  0  0 0 0
# 9    9  0  1  0  1  0 0 0
# 10  10  0  0  1  0  0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved by `split`ting on the `,`, the `stack` it to a two column data.frame and get the frequency with `table`

```
df1 <- na.omit(stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(df$f, ","), 
          as.numeric), seq_len(nrow(df))))[, 2:1])
table(df1)
#  values
#ind  6 8 10 11 12 17 18
#  1  0 0  0  0  0  0  0
#  2  0 0  1  0  0  1  1
#  3  0 1  0  0  1  0  0
#  4  1 0  0  1  0  1  0
#  5  0 0  0  0  0  0  1
#  6  0 0  0  0  1  0  0
#  7  0 0  0  0  1  0  0
#  8  0 0  0  0  0  0  0
#  9  0 0  0  1  0  1  0
#  10 0 0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: `stringi::stri_split_*` is vectorized (so no need to wrap it with lapply), and also will be more performant than strsplit. But it hiccups on NA rows, so that sort of undoes the good, and means you still need lapply