# Splitting column of comma separated categories into binary matrix

Tags: r, split, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

I'm pretty new to R and I really need some help. I have a column `cats` in my dataframe which i would like to spread into a binary matrix where 1 is where the respondent reported interest in and 0 if they did not.

I've found that my problem is very similar to the one here:

[Split column of comma-separated numbers into multiple columns based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650152/split-column-of-comma-separated-numbers-into-multiple-columns-based-on-value)

However I am unable to solve my problem using the said solution and keep receiving multiple different errors at different points. I suspect it's because my data frame contains strings and not integers or numbers.

Here is a sample data frame of what I am working with

```
df <- data.frame(c("sports", "business,IT,entertainment", "feature,entertainment", "business,politics,sports", "health", "politics", "reviews", "entertainment,health", "IT"))

colnames(df) <- "cats"

#                       cats
#1                    sports
#2 business,IT,entertainment
#3     feature,entertainment
#4  business,politics,sports
#5                    health
#6                  politics
#7                   reviews
#8      entertainment,health
#9                        IT
```

And this is what I'm trying to make it look like

```
        sports business IT entertainment politics review health feature    
1         1       0     0        0          0        0      0      0
2         0       1     1        1          0        0      0      0
3         0       0     0        1          0        0      0      1
4         1       1     0        0          1        0      0      0
etc...
```

Examples of errors I have received are:

```
Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context

Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object '' not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly what `cSplit_e` from "splitstackshape" is for: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit_e(df, "cats", ",", type = "character")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
+with(df, sapply(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(cats), ","))), grepl, cats))
#      sports business IT entertainment feature politics health reviews
# [1,]      1        0  0             0       0        0      0       0
# [2,]      0        1  1             1       0        0      0       0
# [3,]      0        0  0             1       1        0      0       0
# [4,]      1        1  0             0       0        1      0       0
# [5,]      0        0  0             0       0        0      1       0
# [6,]      0        0  0             0       0        1      0       0
# [7,]      0        0  0             0       0        0      0       1
# [8,]      0        0  0             1       0        0      1       0
# [9,]      0        0  1             0       0        0      0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Based on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650152/split-column-of-comma-separated-numbers-into-multiple-columns-based-on-value) you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
   df %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var="row") %>% 
  separate_rows(cats, sep=",") %>% 
  count(row, cats) %>% 
  spread(cats, n, fill = 0)
```

Edit thanks to @eipi10

Answer (score 0):

One option with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$cats), ","))
#  business entertainment feature health IT politics reviews sports
#1        0             0       0      0  0        0       0      1
#2        1             1       0      0  1        0       0      0
#3        0             1       1      0  0        0       0      0
#4        1             0       0      0  0        1       0      1
#5        0             0       0      1  0        0       0      0
#6        0             0       0      0  0        1       0      0
#7        0             0       0      0  0        0       1      0
#8        0             1       0      1  0        0       0      0
#9        0             0       0      0  1        0       0      0
```

---

Or with `table` from `base R`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$cats), ","), seq_len(nrow(df))))[2:1])
```